# Distinct count mdx fails

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a question about performing a distinct count of number of clients in my `OLAP` cube.

My clients-dimension table is populated from 4 different databases, this means that I can find the same clients with different Clients_ID (Natural key), because each client has a different ID in every database.

I want to calculate a distinct count on client’s phone number because it’s the same record in all Databases, I always get a big number which is not the right result.  I checked deeply the issue and I found that the query I set seems to not perform the distinct count right on the phone number.

The small test I did with only filters (see screenshot below) let me believe that my query is performing the distinct count on each client ID instead of the phone number.

The query for the little test, I did it with the design mode :

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[QQT - Fact Ventes] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX].[FaCuNumberX].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES
MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Date].[MonthOfYear].&[7] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX].&[8817], [DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX].&[39223] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Date].[Year].&[2014] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [CubeAll]))) 
WHERE ( [Dim Date].[Year].&[2014], [Dim Date].[MonthOfYear].&[7] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

[image]

Here it is the query I used to perform my distinct count:

```
WITH 
  SET MySet AS
    Filter(
      {[Dim Date].[Year].&[2014]} 
      *
      {[DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX].[FaCuNumberX]},
      [Measures].[QQT - Fact Ventes]>1 
      OR  
      [Measures].[QQT - Fact Ventes]=1
    )
  MEMBER MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT AS
    DISTINCTCOUNT(MySet)
SELECT 
  {MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT} ON 0
FROM [CubeAll]
```

The output of My distinct count query :

[image]

I tested also an alternative query, but the same result (see screenshot below):

[image]

I'll put also the SQL query that gives the right expected result :

[image]

I don’t know why the filter on this mdx query doesn’t work properly like an SQL group by.

Comment: Your query does not match the result: The query has no `rows` section, hence will only return one row. The result screen shot shows two rows as result.

Comment: Yes you're right; the result I gave is another test I performed to check out why my distinct count is always turning a huge number of clients. The small test I did is a simple filter on customer phone number, as you could see in the screenshot the same client is shown tow times, I pushed my exploration furthermore, I found that the transactions come from tow different databases.

Comment: Could you edit your question and put a result there that matches the query, or a query that gets the result you put there?

Comment: I've added the query of my test, please note this part of the query " SELECT ( { [DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX].&[8817], [DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX].&[39223]" , in fact 8817 and 39223 are the IDs of the client and what I can't understand is the field [DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX] contains the phone number not the id.

Comment: Thus, the `4` in the result is not a problem, but the result of your second query is not as you expected?

Comment: Would moving the year to the WHERE condition, i. e. `WITH 
  SET MySet AS
    Filter([DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX].[FaCuNumberX],
      [Measures].[QQT - Fact Ventes]>=1 
    )
  MEMBER MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT AS
    DISTINCTCOUNT(MySet)
SELECT 
  {MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT} ON 0
FROM [CubeAll]
WHERE [Dim Date].[Year].&[2014]` give you the result you expected?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, still I got the same wrong result.
Here it is the SQL query that I’m using to confirm on my data warehouse. 
`use [Warehouse]

select count(*) as count_row

From 
(Select  F.FaCunumberX
from [dbo].[Dim_FaClients] F
inner join [dbo].[FACT_Ventes] V on F.[SK_FAClients] = V.SK_FaClients
inner join [dbo].[Dim_Date] D on D.SK_Date = V.SK_Date
where
D.Year = '2014'
Group by F.FaCunumberX
having  SUM(V.QQT) >= 1) test`

Right now I’m wondering if there is another way to model this directly on the warehouse.

Comment: What is the output of your second query? You still did not put that anywhere. Especially, what is the output for the row for the phone number that you show in the answer of your first query. As we do not have your cube available, it is a bit difficult to guess the output if you do not state it.

Comment: I've added all the outputs, thanks for helping.

Comment: How are "Dim Date" and "Dim FA Clients" related to the measure group in your cube? DO they both have a regular relationship via the dimension key?

Comment: Yes, they are related to the fact table [FACT_Ventes] with a surrogate key : SK-FaClient and SK-Date

Comment: Just a guess: What happens if you replace `DISTINCTCOUNT` with `COUNT`?

Comment: I got the same result with both `DISTINCTCOUNT` and `COUNT`